# tinyMCE - block format

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have this tinyMCE instance:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tinymce',
    style_formats: [
        [...]
        {title: 'Em', format: 'em'}
        [...]
    ],
    formats : {
        em : { block : 'em', exact : true }
    },
```

I want to format the selected text to appear within `<em>` tags, not `<p>`. When I modify the block variable to `<div>` or even `<h1>`, it is working, but with `<em>`, it wraps the whole `<em></em>` in `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The `block` property needs to specify a block level element. An `<em>` is an inline element. Change `block: 'em'` to `inline: 'em'`.